# View overlapping each other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view, android-tablelayout

I have an activity in which my views (table and headertable) are overlapping

```
private ViewGroup createTable(ViewGroup root) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TableLayout table = new TableLayout(getActivity());
    table.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    table.setShrinkAllColumns(true);

    TableLayout headertable = new TableLayout(getActivity());
    headertable.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    headertable.setShrinkAllColumns(true);

    /* Adding stuff to headertable which contains...  */
            /* ...table content I DO NOT WANT to scroll*/

    root.addView(headertable);

    for (int i = -2; i <= 100; i++) {

                    if (i > 0) {
            /*Set up empty views*/
                /*...3 empty views will be set*/
                    }

        /* Adding stuff to table which contains...  */
                    /* ...table content I WANT to scroll*/

    }

    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(getActivity());
    sv.addView(table);
    root.addView(sv);
    return root;
}
```

I basically broke a table into headertable and table. I want to scroll table but not headertable. However, my table(which should be below headertable), is overlapping it. Hence, as you can see above I added empty views(so it starts off below headertable(which has three rows)), but realized this would not work. As soon as I scrolled down, the empty views slide up and my headertable gets obstructed again.

All my views have been made programmatically. This activity is a fragment activity.
The XML file contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff" >

</FrameLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess the big question is: what kind of layout is `root`? Is it the `FrameLayout` you post at the end? If so, you probably want to exchange it for a vertically-oriented `LinearLayout` that will automatically position the header and `ScrollView` below each other. `FrameLayout`s aren't really suitable for hosting multiple children (unless you *want* those to overlap). Also, what is `table2`, as I don't see that variable being constructed anywhere.

Comment: First off, thanks for the response. Table2 should be headertable. I've updated it now. Apparently, I forgot to commit the changes before posting here. And no, its not a framelayout, it is a fragment inside a linearlayout. Like I said it is a fragment activity, and so has to return root(which is a fragment) to the main FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the best way, but here's how I do it:

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/pane"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**header_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <ListView
            android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/header" />
    <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/header"
            android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**RecipeListFragment.java**

```
public class RecipeListFragment extends ListFragment {
    private TextView header;
    private TextView empty;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.common_list, container, false);
        header = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.header);
        empty = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
        header.setText(R.string.header_recipe);
        empty.setText(R.string.empty_recipes);
        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // List code here
    }
}
```

This code only has a single header line, but you can change that TextView to a TableLayout and then fill it the same way, giving you your header table and putting the list underneath it so that it won't scroll over the top of it.

Hope this helps!